# Negative number in ARINC-429

Tags: arinc-429

I'm a little bit confused by representation of negative number in ARINC-429.
Let's consider the following example:

1. Significant bits is equal to 7 (it does not count sign bit),
2. Resolution is equal to 1,
3. DATA section has to represent -1 value.
   Initially I thought that DATA section is represented as follows:

   ```
   1 1 1 | 1 1 1 1 | 1 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 0
   ```

But I'm confused by sensor documentation. There sign bit is not in DATA section and I started to think that maybe bits 29-11 should look like that:

```
1 0 0 | 0 0 0 0 | 1 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 0
```

Which way of thinking is correct?

Answer (score 1):

BNR labels that can be negative are represented in 2's complement form

**2.3.1.1 Numeric Data**

> The Mark 33 DITS should accommodate numeric data
> encoded in two digital languages, (i) BNR expressed in
> twos complement fractional notation and (ii) BCD per the
> numerical subset of ISO Alphabet Number 5

If your label is indicating 7 significant bits and an LSB of 1, your range must be +/-128. Bit 29 is the sign bit, and the data bits work down from there.

> -1 = 1 1 1 | 1 1 1 1 | 1 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 0